# Navigation Drawer fragments recreated on click. Need to reuse instance of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, savestate

So I use the sliding menu with a few fragments in my application. The issue is that the every time I click on a new fragment in the navigation drawer it appears to completely destroy the old fragment. Either that or the new fragment forces itself to be recreated whenever I click it. Basically I want to know how I can reuse the same instance of the fragment I had whenever I click it. I've looked all over stackoverflow and can't seem to find an answer that works.

Here is my main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;



    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    private Fragment mContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();





        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));



        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);





    }


/**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {


            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);



        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            onLogout();

            break;
        default:

            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }


    protected void onLogout() {
            try {
                // clearing app data
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                runtime.exec("pm clear com.nsi.StudentConnection");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        ListFragment lf = null;
        String TAG;

        switch (position) {






        case 0:

            fragment = new GradeFragment();
            TAG = "grade";
            break;

        case 1:
            lf = new IrvingFragment();
            TAG = "irving";
            break;



            case 2:
            fragment = new HomeworkFragment();
            TAG = "homework";
            break;

        //case 2:
            //fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
            //break;




        default:
            fragment = new GradeFragment();
            TAG = "grade";
            break;
        }


        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, TAG)


                    .commit();




            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }

        if (lf != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, lf)


                    .commit();




            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

and here is one of my Fragment classes

```
public class HomeworkFragment extends Fragment {



public HomeworkFragment(){}
protected CheckBox checkbox;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

final String myTag = "DocsUpload";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setRetainInstance(true);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homework, container, false);

    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean dialogShown = settings.getBoolean("dialogShown", false);

     if (dialogShown != true) {
    Dialog dialog = createDialog();
    dialog.show();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putBoolean("dialogShown", true);
     editor.commit();

     }

    return rootView;


}


 public Dialog createDialog()
 {






        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.rebuild_form_title)
               .setMessage(R.string.rebuild_instructions)

               .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog

                   }

               });


        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it



     return builder.create();
 }





    private void doNotShowAgain() {
        // persist shared preference to prevent dialog from showing again.
        Log.d("MainActivity", "TODO: Persist shared preferences.");

        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);



    }
```

Comment: why dont you check your fragment backstack if the fragment is present if yes show the one in backstack

Comment: illegal Argument, How would I go about doing that? I've used the addToBackStack() method in the fragment manager transaction but that only restores the old instance if I press the back button. Not if I click on it in the navigation drawer unfortunately

Comment: in your fragmet's onstart method first check if the fragment is present in backstack then if yes show that else start new one you havent used addToBackStack(null) have you??

Comment: I used addToBackStack(null) before but removed it. I guess I should probably re-add it in there. I'm pretty new to Android development. Would you mind showing me sample code of how to check and show a fragment in the backstack?  I assume i'd use the .popBackStack method but i'm not really sure. And I would call this method in the Fragments onStart method and not the activity that handles the fragments onStart? Thank you for your help!

Comment: hi user3047107, did you find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately not Vihaan Verma. Still a frustrating issue. I plan on trying to keep looking in a couple weeks.